# Trouble moving freepbx and a2billing

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freepbx

I'm having trouble moving from FreePBX 2.9.0.15 and A2Billing 1.7.1 to FreePBX 2.11.0.43 and A2Billing 2.2.0
I've transfer the A2Billing data via the backup and restore feature without any problem. This wasn't the case for FreePBX, so I used the Bulk Extension feature, the manually checked every extension(actually I did this a few times), the I manually moved all trunks(most of them are SIP, and there are 3 custom), then I moved the outbound routes, I've checked all the information more than two times so everything is supposed to be correct. I've also moved other configuration for the Freepbx such as firewall rules. Everything seems to work fine, I can make phone calls except the fact that A2Billing doesn't log them, when I go to Call reports and then CDRs, it doesn't display anything from the dates I've tested, the same when I go to call reports and them call count. On other hand the SIP which are connecting the network to the outside world, aren't installed yet so when I make call it says that the line is busy, which is normal. One thing that bothers me is that there are two custom trunks - "A2B/2" and "Local/$OUTNUM$" which are suppose to be the connection to the a2billing or something similar, since the other trunks, which are connected to the providers aren't added to any route, however I can't find any information for them, I can't even find them in the configuration files in folder /etc/asterisk. I haven't installed the system and the configuration isn't documented so I can't provide any more information about those trunks, however I'm pretty sure they are cause of the problem. Here is their configuration:

```
Local/$OUTNUM$
Trunk Name: Local/$OUTNUM$
! All other options are set to the default values !
Dialed Number Manipulation Rules
(prepend)(prefix)(ZXX)
Outbound Dial Prefix: 024210
Custom Dial String: Local/$OUTNUM$

A2B/2

Trunk Name: A2B/2
! All other options are set to the default values !
Dialed Number Manipulation Rules
(prepend)(prefix)(ZXXXXXX)
(prepend)(prefix)(ZXXXXX)
Outbound Dial Prefix: 02
Custom Dial String: A2B/2
```

Those two trunks are connected to the routes, one named Local connected to the first trunk, which matches the following pattern:

```
()()NXX
```

And other one names city which matches the following patterns:

```
  ()()112
  ()()ZXXXX
  ()()ZXXXXX
  ()()ZXXXXXX
```

Any ideas how I can continue troubleshooting and what may be causing the problmen